# How to get all azure app registrations and view expiry date of secrets using a app registrations and azure cli commands?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get all the azure app registrations and view expiry date of secrets using a app registrations and azure cli commands, provided below permissions to the app registration.
[image]

But, getting below message while login in to the Azure AD using the service principal name and cli commands.

[image]

Also, This --allow-no-subscriptions option did not help.

[image]

Please share your suggestions and comments.
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Your Service Principal needs to have [`Application Administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-administrator) role assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error means your service principal is not in any Azure Subscription, as you used, you could use `--allow-no-subscriptions` to solve this.

The second error means your service principal does not have the permission to run the command `az ad app list`, i.e. list the app registrations in the AAD tenant.

To solve the issue, you have two options.

1.Add permission  *Application permission* in `Azure Active Directory Graph` e.g. `Application.Read.All`(**Note**: Not `Microsoft Graph`).

[image]

[image]

[image]

2.Give an [Azure AD admin role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference) e.g. `Application Administrator` to your service principal as mentioned in the comment, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/manage-roles-portal).

Comment: Joy Wang-MSFT- It works like a charm ! Thank you very much but one questions Microsoft Azure saying from June 30th, 2020 they did not add any new features to Azure AD Graph API and strongly recommending to use Microsoft Graph API instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory resources.

Comment: @ThadikaranK Yes, but the Azure CLI still calls the Azure AD Graph, so we need to add the permission of it. You can also use option 2 as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much Joy Wang for the information.  I will try that option 2.